# Export NativeModules for NPM in React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, npm, react-native, node-modules

I'm trying to create a node module from my React Native App. The problem is, that the module is mostly a NativeModule. So my index.js looks like this:

```js
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
export default NativeModules.MyNativeClass;
```

When i install my package to my node_modules (inserted local relative path to package.json) and import it to my JS file, it's always undefined. 
I tried to export a test object, like `export default {test:'test'};` and it works. So, is it possible to export the Native Module through node_modules?

Comment: do you have react-native package in same node_modules directory where you installed your module? It is usually specified as a peer dependency for libraries

Comment: yes, i have all required dependencies as peerDependencies in the module, also react-native.

Comment: Strange. is NativeModules that is undefined or MyNativeClass that is undefined?

Comment: The NativeModules is an empty object if i only export it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is stuck to the same issue. Just link it with

> react-native link

and your native modules from your node_modules get visible.